# Rewrite url with query parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to rewrite a specific url and remove the query parameter. However online I can't seem to find a solution which works for me. I'm pretty new to .htacces files and the working of them.

My file for now, which is in the main folder of my website:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

#Remove php extension
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

#Remove html extension
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

#Remove id query parameter
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^webhook/(.*)$ webhook.php?q=$1
```

So the normal url is: https://example.com/api/webhook.php?id=10

which I want rewrite as: https://example.com/api/webhook/10

Does anyone know how to create this for this specific case? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

In my webhook.php file I have this for testing purposes:

```
<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
```

When I go to the url https://example.com/api/webhook.php?id=10 I get output 10 in the browser.

When I go to the url https://example.com/api/webhook/10

I get this error message:
*Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.*

And in the serverlogs I found this error:
*Request exceeded the limit of 4 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace*

Seems there are too many rewrites.

**SOLVED**
I found that these lines fixed my problem:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule   ^api/webhook/(.+)$   api/webhook.php?id=$1   [L]
```

Now when I go to https://examply.com/api/webhook/10 it loads the webhook.php script with query ?id=10. The page now outputs '10'.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working yet? Why do you use `RewriteEngine on` multiple times?

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts. Could you please do confirm if you are hitting link `https://example.com/api/webhook.php?id=10` in browser?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I updated my question with some new information. I indeed went to that url.

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks! I updated my question with some more info.

Comment: "Internal Server Error" sounds like you should check your server's error log for more details

Comment: Ah yes. This is the error: Request exceeded the limit of 4 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace @NicoHaase

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: For example: why does the first rule rewrite all requests ending in `.php` to files ending with `.php`? Does that make any sense?

Comment: @NicoHaase to remove .php from all url's. For example /api/index.php to /api/index. As I said, I am pretty new to this. I found this solution online te remove .php from all pages

Comment: _"My file for now, which is in the main folder of my website"_ - then the pattern `^webhook/(.*)$` will not match to begin with, because the path of your URL, minus the "prefix" that leads to the folder where your .htaccess is located, is `api/webhook/10`

Comment: I found the solution. Found that 'RewriteRule   ^api/webhook/(.+)$   api/webhook.php?id=$1   [L]' works perfectly to create the URL that I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^api/webhook/([0-9]+)/?$ api/webhook.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Usage = These rules will make your url https://example.com/api/webhook.php?id=10 to https://example.com/api/webhook/10